# WPF C# Text between line

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF UI, I want to show text between horizontal line.

something like this image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pad Left & Pad Right (Pad Center) String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590528/pad-left-pad-right-pad-center-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Rectangle with `Height="1"` and create a label on top of it with `Background="White"`

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Height="1" Stroke="Black"  />
    <Label Content="Text" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to just put a `TextBlock` on top of a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Height="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Black"/>
    <TextBlock Text="TEXT" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               Background="White" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like a Grid with three columns: the second one autosized to its content width (i.e. "TEXT"), and the other two star-sized so they both end up the same width as each other (each taking half of the remaining space).

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="TEXT"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Depending on your font, you might have to play around with adding some top or bottom margins to the Rectangles to get them to line up with the text the way you want - there's unfortunately no built-in way to align it with the text midline.